# Firebase storage - some of downloadURLs is null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

photos is an array filled by blobs

```
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

      for(let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
          let photoName = photos[i].file.name;
          if(photos[i].resized) photos[i] = this.dataURLToBlob(photos[i].resized.dataURL);
          var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/' + this.userInfo.uid + '/offers/' + new Date().getTime() + photoName).put(photos[i], metadata);
          uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
          }, function(error) {
          }, function() {
            console.log(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
.
.
.
```

I have a problem with asynchronous, because sometimes (every time actually) console.log prints few null.

For example I upload 3 photos.
I get a message:

```
null
2x third photo download url
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in

`var uploadTask =...` which should be `let uploadTask = ...`

Comment: yeah, that's Javacript!